# AWS SAM missing authentication token when redirect from AzureAD

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, azure-active-directory, aws-serverless, aws-sam

I am using [this instruction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/web-app-quickstart?pivots=devlang-python) from AzureAD to authenticate the application, and this is working, but when I am trying to integrate it into the AWS SAM, then I get `{"message": "Missing Authentication Token"}` when the application try to redirect.

here is part of SAM template:

```
Resources:
  HelloWorldFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      CodeUri: hello_world/
      Handler: app.app
      Runtime: python3.9
      Architectures:
        - x86_64
      Events:
        HelloWorld:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            Path: /
            Method: get
```

so the login page is fine, I can see that with the API Gateways URL + `/Prod` but when I am logged in then is throw me the message `{"message": "Missing Authentication Token"}` and the URL is `https://asdverftgsd.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/Prod/getAToken?code=xxxxx`

and this is the URL that I've registered in AzureAD
`https://asdverftgsd.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/Prod/getAToken`

any idea what could be missed? I've tried also to add the new path to SAM template but none of them worked:

```
Events:
    HelloWorld:
    ...
    getToken:
      Type: Api
      Properties:
        Path: /getAToken
        # Path: /Prod/getAToken
        # Path: /Prod/getAToken{token} # this is not accepted by SAM
        Method: get
```